# Cannot find the input date into the textbox

Tags: c#, database, date

How can I search my date into the datagrid view? I have a sample code which I think is correct but why does it not search?

[image]

```
    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text))
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from STUDENT_RESEARCH_PROJECTS WHERE COURSE LIKE '" + comboBox2.Text + "%'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }

        else
        {
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ACCESSION_NO,TITLE_PROJECT,CATEGORY,YEAR,COURSE,DATE,Student_Name1,Student_Name2,Student_Name3,Student_Name4,Student_Name5,RELATED_TITLE1,RELATED_TITLE2,RELATED_TITLE3,RELATED_TITLE4,RELATED_TITLE5 FROM STUDENT_RESEARCH_PROJECTS WHERE DATE LIKE'" + textBox3.Text + "%'", con);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is the Property of the textbox3 set? What does the debugger say?
What type does the date-column in the database have? Not sure if you can query a date with like. Also you should be aware of sql-injection but I am sure, thats only for the sample :-)

Comment: Ever heard of SQL-injection?

Comment: Have you run your query directly against the database? does it return any records? Take the query along with textbox3.Text and try to run against the database first.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `LIKE` for date comparison unless your `DATE` field is a string

Also you need to check how is the date data saved into database

For example in my database I am using `datetime` which is being saved like `2018-03-20 07:25:58.557`

So when you are querying you need to put a format of your date in order to be accepted

Answer (score 0):

First be aware SQL injection.

you cannot use like operator on `Date` Column.

Your search TextBox value date format is `03/20/2018(mm/dd/yyyy)` and database column contains something different which is usually `2018-03-20 00:00:00.000` to search with the date change the format when querying from database like this.

```
    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty("textBox3.Text"))
        {
            string query = "Select * from STUDENT_RESEARCH_PROJECTS WHERE COURSE LIKE @COURSE";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COURSE", comboBox2.Text);

            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }

        else
        {
            string query = "SELECT ACCESSION_NO,TITLE_PROJECT,CATEGORY,YEAR,COURSE,DATE,Student_Name1,Student_Name2,Student_Name3,Student_Name4,Student_Name5,RELATED_TITLE1,RELATED_TITLE2,RELATED_TITLE3,RELATED_TITLE4,RELATED_TITLE5 FROM STUDENT_RESEARCH_PROJECTS WHERE CONVERT(varchar(10) ,DATE, 101)  = @DATE";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DATE", textBox3.Text);
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
            DataTable data = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(data);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data;
        }
    }
```